# How to make cell grid size change while grid size remains constant?

Tags: javascript, css

Elements not resizing to fit space

I'm making an Etch-A-Sketch which consists of a grid with x amount of cells. The size of the grid is supposed to always stay the same while the size of the cells should resize so that all of the cells fit into the specified grid.

When I tried running my code, the size of the cell grid always changes while the size of the cells is constant. In addition, the grid grows to overlap with other elements like buttons.

This is the javascript (I want the grid to grow to fit the .board element):

```
const board = document.querySelector(".board");
let rows = document.getElementsByClassName("gridRow");
let cells = document.getElementsByClassName("cell");

let gridNumber = prompt("How many cells wide would you like your grid to be?");
if(gridNumber>50){
    alert("Sorry, this grid is too big");
    gridNumber = 20;
}

function makeRows(rowNum){
    for(let i=0; i<rowNum; i++){
        let row = document.createElement("div");
        board.appendChild(row).className = "gridRow";
    }
}

function makeCells(cellNum){
    for(let i=0; i<rows.length; i++){
        for(let j=0; j<cellNum; j++){
            let cell = document.createElement("div");
            cell.addEventListener("mouseover", () => {
               cell.classList.add('hover'); 
            });
            rows[i].appendChild(cell).className = "cell";
        }
    }
}

makeRows(gridNumber);
makeCells(gridNumber);

document.getElementById("reset").onclick = function() {
    for(let i=0; i<cells.length; i++)
        cells[i].classList.remove('hover');
}
```

This is the CSS:

```
body{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
}
.cell{
    border: 1px solid black;   
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    flex: 1;
    background-color: white;
}

#container{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    min-width: 500px;
    min-height: auto;
    align-items: center;
}

.board{
    display: flex;
    flex: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: row;
    background-color: black;
    margin: 20px;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
}

.hover{
    background-color: green;
}
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="etchsketch.js" defer></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="etchsketch.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div class = "title"><h1>Etch-A-Sketch</h1></div>
        <div class = board></div>
        <div class = buttons>
            <button id = "reset">Reset</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

While I realize that this project could be more easily done with CSS grid, I wanted to know if theres a way to do it using cells made in javascript.

Comment: I'm not clear exactly what the constraints are. Is each individual cell supposed to grow or shrink as necessary in order that the whole board fits into the container? I don't understand therefore why cells are given 10px width and height.